# How to declare (and add content to) a List in an interface

Tags: java, interface

Using a Java `interface`, i'd like to declare a `static final List<String>` and add content to it.

So, thing like

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String();
a.add("a");
a.add("b");
```

In an interface. How can this be done please?

Comment: Interfaces don't have code.  can you elaborate on what you want with the interface?

Comment: This can't be done in an interface, you should rather use an abstract class

Comment: Wouldn't you be looking for the singleton pattern, by any chance?

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: It absolutely *can* be done in an interface. It probably *shouldn't* be, but it can.

Comment: @jon skeet yeah just realised from belOw answer... :p

Comment: @downvoter ... whats the problem with a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one line initialization like this:

```
static final List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

Comment: While this is an interesting answer, is debatable this kind of design.

Comment: @JonSkeet why this should be avoided only because of static call or something else related to design pattern.

Comment: @AndroidKiller: Interface fields are only meant to be for *constants* - I don't think it makes much sense for an interface field to be a `List<String>`... particularly not a *mutable* one as per your implementation. An *immutable* one would be slightly better, but still not something I'd generally encourage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collections.unmodifiableList()`

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String();
a.add("a");
a.add("b");

static final List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(a);
```